# Norm of different is the discriminant.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

For a finite extension $K/F$ of local ultrametric fields, where $π_K$ is a uniformizing parameter, show that the norm of $π_K^d$ is the discriminant, where $d$ is the largest integer such that $tr(\mathcal{O}_K/π_K^d) \subset \mathcal{O}_F$.  Here the discriminant is defined as the determinant of the matrix whose entries are $tr(e_ie_j)$, where the $e_i$ form a basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$ over $\mathcal{O}_F$.

Comment: See Neukirch, *Algebraic Number Theory*, Chapter III.2, Theorem 2.9.

Comment: The notions of different and discriminant, and their interrelationship, are not specifically local ones. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1912067/300700